# Django Server as a Windows Service

Tags: django, windows, cmd, windows-services

I have a batch File that runs Django Server and it works perfect.

```
c:\Python27\python.exe manage.py runserver 8003
```

and  that I am using a 3rd Party app NSSM https://nssm.cc/

Which run my Batch file as a Windows Service. 
the point is the Service does not start the Server. How can I run the server using this service; the service will open the cmd and execute the command.
Should I use another 3rd party app or is there any command that I can add to my batch file and update it the serive

Comment: You *must not* use the development server in a production setting. Use a proper web server, which will already know how to start itself as a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run django as a Windows service *for development purposes* (see the comment above), I have had good luck with instsrv and srvany, both Windows tools that work on all Windows platforms.  See https://www.iceflatline.com/2015/12/run-a-windows-application-as-a-service-with-srvany/ for details.